# AppStore In App Purchase Usage - Detecting possible rejection causes

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have a service that I supply to my users within my app. It might considered as a question, and you need to use in-app purchase in order to send this question, later to be replied.

I didn't wanted to implement an account-based app, so I used other unique identifier in order to identify users (asking questions, and being able to see your questions/answers). No account information, cannot use credit based approach.

The only spot that I can implement the in-app purchase is the send button of the question, where to action is being taken. Does apple allow attaching in-app purchase functionality on such condition. If not, could anyone propose another approach to solve this issue.

Comment: You want to just have in-app functionality work on the send button? Is that the basic question?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I want to know, if its allowed or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From previous IAP experience I think Apple might take issue with the send button actually initiating the transaction; it's not entirely obvious to the user that this is something that will initiate a purchase, and at the very least it's liable to lead to some confusion.

A more conventional approach would be to have users buy "credits" to ask questions; they can buy one or more of them at a time (maybe a good thing for your sales anyway - sell them a pack of 10 at a 20% discount, say, and they might buy more) from a separate screen. The number of credits would show up next to the "send" button, and if they have no credits left, when they tap on "send" an alert comes up offering to direct them to that other screen to buy credits. (tapping on the current number of credits / the text indicating that they don't have any credits might also bring up this screen)

This approach is incredibly popular - used by tons of games, among other things - so it's something the Apple reviewer would probably recognize right away as an OK / standard practice.

Comment: i guess we are going with that anyway =) any suggestions on how to bypass account(eg. username/password) while using credits. Using Unique Device IDs?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't want them to have to log in each time they use a credit, or each time they buy one?

Comment: they don't have to login in to use the application at all, not for buying credits and not for spending them

Comment: No way to avoid the requirement that they log in to their iTunes account to buy credits, but if credits are server-based then a device ID certainly might be a reasonable way to tag them - added benefit is that you can check receipts against that ID for security (and save them / re-check them on use, if you want). Just make sure to use the newer iOS 6 device ID API when your app is running on an OS 6 device, as [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier] is officially deprecated.